# Listing and callergraphs for variables in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

Is there any possibility to automatically list all variables that are called in a function in the function description?

Is it also possible to create some kind of graphs that show, which functions within a file call a certain variable?

Added 2018-02-20:

I'm using doxygen 1.8.14.
Here is an example of what I would like to do:

Example.h

```
class Example
{
    public:
     void set_test(int invar);
     int get_test();
     void do_nothing();
    private:
       int _test_var;    ///< Comment on what variable does
       int _test2;
};
```

Example.cpp

```
#include "Example.h"

/** /brief Description of Function set_test*/
void Example::set_test(int invar)
{
   _test_var=invar;
}
/** /brief Description of Function get_test*/
int Example::get_test()
{
    _test2 = _test_var;
    return _test_var;
}
/** /brief Description of function do_nothing*/
int Example::do_nothing()
{
   delay (1000);
}
```

What I want doxygen to do is to show the all functions in which _test_var is called (set_test, get_test) at the place where the this variable is explained.

Further I would like to list all variables, that are called inside a function at the place where the function is explained. (e.g. for get_test() the list would show _test2 and _test_var)

This would allow me to get an overview over which function influences which variable.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Please explain what you really want to have and show some code to explain it more clearly. What do you mean with "call a certain variable"?

Comment: Did you have a look at e.g. EXTRACT_..., REFERENCED_BY_RELATION and REFERENCES_RELATION in the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile)? It won't create a graph though of variables. An approach might be use the xml output and process this to a graph.

Answer (score 1):

This comment did answer my question:

> Did you have a look at e.g. EXTRACT_..., REFERENCED_BY_RELATION and 
>   REFERENCES_RELATION in the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile)? It won't 
>   create a graph though of variables. An approach might be use the xml output 
>   and process this to a graph

REFERENCED_BY_RELATION shows a list of all functions that refer to the documented function or variable.

REFERENCES_RELATION lists all functions and variables that are called within the documented function.

Comment: Which part of the comment did answer your question? What did you use and what are the results. The comment only gave some pointers.